# fractions Display Error

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, php

I migrated my website to new server. However, i got the error with fractions Display.

Here is the error: 
[image]

On the old server:

[image]

I installed the same extensions for php. What am I missing?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

It is related to default character in php. So I commented out in php.ini and restarted Apache. It worked perfectly.

default_charset = "iso-8859-1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to default character in php. So I commented it out in php.ini and restarted apache. It worked perfectly.

default_charset = "iso-8859-1"

Answer (score 0):

Check your `httpd.conf` file for mention of `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`. If it's not there or is anything other than `utf-8` (like perhaps `iso-8859-1`) then add that line in the appropriate area.

To verify what's happening, check the HTTP response headers for the website that isn't showing fractions properly and I'll bet you see `Content-Type text/html` with no mention of a charset. That means that unicode fraction symbols are not going to render properly.

For more information, [check Apache's official core documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset).

Comment: I've already added it.

Comment: Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8